# How to strip time from date time into DDMMYYYY from DDMMYYY:HH:MM:SS

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a data frame with a column that is filled with dates time.

```
str(df$date)
char [1:2000] "01JAN2015:12:20:00" "19JUN2015:15:30:00" "19OCT2013:05:26:00"
```

I want to strip time and just have the column being left with DDMMYYY such as

```
01JAN2015 19JUN2015 19OCT2013
```

I have tried `df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date)` and the output was

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

or the `df$date <- as.Date(df$date)` and the output was

```
Error in charToDate(x) :
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I would greatly appreciate help.

Thanks

Comment: `sub(":.*$", "", df$date)` to keep just the dates.  Then use the argument `format`, function `as.Date`.

Comment: `substr(df$date,1,9)` or `as.Date(df$date,format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")` also work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert to date and strip time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366703/convert-to-date-and-strip-time)

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate`:

`df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d%b%Y")`

will give you:

[1] "2015-01-01" "2015-06-19" "2013-10-19"

Hope it helps you

Comment: I have just tried that and when I do the str(df$date) the output is `Date[1:2000], format: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...`

Comment: `as.Date(c("01JAN2015:12:20:00", "19JUN2015:15:30:00", "19OCT2013:05:26:00"), "%d%b%Y")` gives `[1] "2015-01-01" "2015-06-19" "2013-10-19"` so the answer works on the data in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- c("01JAN2015:12:20:00", "19JUN2015:15:30:00", "19OCT2013:05:26:00")
dates <- sub(":.*$", "", dates) %>% dmy(.) %>% gsub("-", "", .)
paste0(substr(dates, 7, 8), substr(dates, 5, 6), substr(dates, 1, 4))
# [1] "01012015" "19062015" "19102013"
```

Comment: I have tired your suggestion. But I am reaching this warning message `All formats failed to parse. No formats found` Thank you

Comment: @B.Choi How strange. When you type `R.version` what do you get? I’m on 3.5.0 and it works perfectly as intended

Comment: I am on `R version 3.5.1`